# How to open the shortest path of google map navigation in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm opening a google map using my android program. I did it with the following URL,

> http://maps.google.com/maps?     saddr=31.186371,121.489885&daddr=31.249351,121.45905&mode=driving

But this opens a view like,
[image]

I want to open the shortest path(1st one in list view) from these paths. Is there a way to do this? How may I do this?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation), you can launch the turn by turn navigation by this intent:

```
google.navigation:q=a+street+address
```

you can use these code to launch the intent:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

As you might able to tell, this can only give a turn-by-turn direction from `current location` to `point A`, but not `point A` to `point B`. You should consider using the [web direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) and draw the polyline on your own Google Maps to gain more controls.